# how to set facebook return url

Tags: php, facebook

I have been trying to enable facebook login in my website. For my solution, i followed the following steps:
1.) Landing on website: http://projects.simriksolutions.com/serpicoclient/kool_test.php
2.) When user clicks on **"login"**, then we show up login page: http://projects.simriksolutions.com/serpicoclient/kool_test.php?section=userLogin  with login via facebook and my site's form

3.) Users uses the login via facebook button and logins using facebook credentials  in facebook website.

Up to here its fine... After that the user should return to some other page, i.e: http://projects.simriksolutions.com/serpicoclient/kool_test.php?section=makeFBLogin&returnURL=/serpicoclient/kool_test.php

but m failing on that... after the successful login user is being redirected to http://projects.simriksolutions.com/serpicoclient/

How can i set the returnURL of facebook url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an absolute URL in the `redirect_uri` parameter:
**PHP-SDK**:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'redirect_uri'=>'http://absolute_url'
));
```

Comment: before it didn't worked but later worked fine... didn't know why?

Comment: @KoolKabin: Well, that is odd :-) I have no idea why it wouldn't work from the first time...but glad it's now!

Comment: the correct array value for the new API (as at mid 2012) is 'redirect_uri' rather than 'next'. hopefully this helps because I was stuck on this problem too.