# Facebook PHP SDK: How to redirect to a different page on login?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set facebook return url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167157/how-to-set-facebook-return-url)

I am currently trying to use the official PHP SDK for Facebook. Is there any way to configure it so that Facebook redirects back to a different URL once the user has logged in/accepted the app in facebook?

I've looked around the web and the SDK reference but I can't find the answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just redirect to an URL which is given in the Facebook application settings? You could have all users redirected to this page from Facebook have redirected to another URL again.

Example: `example.com -> facebook.com/authorize_app/whatever -> example.com/redirect -> stackoverflow.com/?param=[fb-access-token]`

You could pass the access token as a parameter in order to be able to access the facebook data on the landing page as well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the getLoginUrl() function in the PHP sdk, it allows you to set the redirect_uri parameter passed to the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) process - this can be any URL owned by your app, though that URL needs to be ready to accept the `code` and exchange it for an access_token to complete the login flow

You can obviously just redirect them after the login completes also, but i assume you're talking about the URL they're brought to as part of the flow